# SonarQube/Azure DevOps code analysis failure - .scannerwork/report-task.txt not found

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube

We run automated code-quality scans in SonarQube that are triggered by pipelines in Azure DevOps:

```
    # retrieve and build code, run unit tests etc.
    - task: SonarQubePrepare@4
      displayName: 'Prepare SonarQube Scan'
      inputs:
        SonarQube: 'SonarQube DevOps Connection'
        scannerMode: 'CLI'
        configMode: 'file'
    - task: SonarQubeAnalyze@4
      displayName: 'Run SonarQube Scan'
    - task: SonarQubePublish@4
      displayName: 'Publish SonarQube Scan Report'
      inputs:
        pollingTimeoutSec: '300'
```

About a week ago, the main analysis task ('Run SonarQube Scan') began failing for all pipelines with the following error:

```
...
##[error]ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
##[error]java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load properties from file /home/vsts/work/1/s/.scannerwork/report-task.txt
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load properties from file /home/vsts/work/1/s/.scannerwork/report-task.txt
...
##[error]Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/vsts/work/1/s/.scannerwork/report-task.txt (No such file or directory)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/vsts/work/1/s/.scannerwork/report-task.txt (No such file or directory)
...
```

We have made no changes to our pipelines, so I am mystified as to what has caused this change.

We are using SonarQube Enterprise EditionVersion 7.9.1 (build 27448) (on-premise installation) and version 4.9.0 of the SonarQube extension for Azure DevOps (published by SonarSource).

UPDATE 25/3/20 (thanks to patricklu-msft):

We are using a Microsoft-hosted build agent with an `ubuntu-16.04` image.  Running the pipeline in debug mode reveals the following:

```
2020-03-25T14:25:00.3694399Z 14:25:00.369 DEBUG: Report metadata written to /home/vsts/work/_temp/sonar/20200325.2/eec0f38a-913b-3db3-e1b2-71091ea5f860/report-task.txt
```

So it appears that the report metadata are being written to `/home/vsts/work/_temp/sonar/20200325.2/eec0f38a-913b-3db3-e1b2-71091ea5f860/report-task.txt` but SonarQube subsequently looks for them in `/home/vsts/work/1/s/.scannerwork/report-task.txt`.  It looks like there is a `mv` operation missing somewhere ...

Comment: What kind of build agents are you using? Host or Self-host agent? Suggest you also enable `system.debug=true` variable in your pipeline, check if you get more detail information for troubleshooting.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT - thanks for your suggestion.  I will add the extra information to the description above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closer inspection of the Azure pipelines logs revealed these two entries that weren't there before:

```
2020-03-26T15:26:44.0989881Z INFO: Executing post-job 'Forbidden Configuration Breaker'
2020-03-26T15:26:44.0990841Z INFO: Executing post-job 'Quality Gate Breaker'
```

Someone installed the [Sonar Build-Breaker Plug-in](https://github.com/adnovum/sonar-build-breaker/tree/master/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/buildbreaker) a week ago without telling us, and none of us have correctly configured it in our pipelines yet.  Setting it to skip the quality gate check (`sonar.buildbreaker.skip=true`) effectively by-passes it (although those two log entries still appear) and the pipelines run successfully once more.

**Update 24/04/2020**: I have now upgraded the Build Breaker plug-in to v2.3.1 (build 347) and that seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's a SonarQube  task side related issue.

According to this link [here](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqubebuildsummary-md-file-empty-with-the-publish-quality-gate-result-step-in-azure-devops/13305):

```
The new version (4.7.x) is looking here:
##[debug]adjustedPattern: 'C:\AzureDevops\Agent2-GCS-Docker\_work\_temp\sonar\199416\**\report-task.txt’
```

Looks like it's supported to look the report-task.txt in temp folder with new version.

Try to roll back your task version and check if this do the trick.

Comment: Thanks again, Patrick.  I have been using version 4.9 since January and my pipelines were quite happy until a week ago ... but your response led me to investigate further and ultimately find the answer.